# 'mavenDeployer' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am attempting to develop my own Android Studio Gradle plugin.

To gain some experience on how to achieve this I am following [this](https://afterecho.uk/blog/create-a-standalone-gradle-plugin-for-android-a-step-by-step-guide.html) tutorial

I have go to the point where I amend the `gradle.build` file as follows:-

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri('repo'))
        }
    }
}
```

I seem to have an issue at this line:-

```
repository(url: uri('repo'))
```

"repository" is underlined and I see this message:-

```
'mavenDeployer' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'
```

I cannot resolve this issue

What have a done wrong?

UPDATE

When I executed the `uploadArchives` task
I was getting this error:-

```
16:47:32: Executing external task 'uploadArchives'...
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.817 secs
Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.4.10 and you are trying to load version 2.3.11
16:47:33: External task execution finished 'uploadArchives'.
```

This was because my `gradle.build` file looked like this:-

```
group 'org.group.id'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}

apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri('repo'))
        }
    }
}
```

When I removed "compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'" and executed the uploadArchives task it all started working ok. Although I still have the same message 'mavenDeployer' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

The output I get when executing the uploadArchives task is:-

```
16:52:00: Executing external task 'uploadArchives'...
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:uploadArchives

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.126 secs
16:52:00: External task execution finished 'uploadArchives'.
```